# Eclipse changes Keyboard layout even without keybindings in windows

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

I have removed my Keybindings in Windows to avoid changing my Keyboard Layout. And it works but if I start Eclipse and press "Ctrl"+ "Space", which is a very important keybinding as you know, changes my Keyboard Layout. The worst Thing is "Ctrl"+ "Space" doesnt work, so I have to write all the stuff by my own. As I said its only in Eclipse.

Comment: Is your keyboard layout changed system-wide or only in eclipse? That means, if you open notepad and test it there, is the layout still wrong?

Comment: Only in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Control Panel -> Region and language -> Change keyboards or other input methods -> Change keyboards... -> Advanced Key Settings -> Change Key Sequence. Then just set another shortcut.

You can also go to Control Panel -> Region and language -> Change keyboards or other input methods -> Change keyboards... and remove all the languages except the one you need.